# Is it possible to reference an object using a string?

Tags: javascript

As a part of my D3.js project I'm using a value chosen by an HTML select box to create a bar chart to display a certain field of data associated with an object. My data object has the fields `this` and `that`.

When my select box is changed it calls a function `selector`

```
function selector() {

//check what box is selected then call render with either this or that

var selected = "this";

render(selected);

}
```

Then, in my function render, I do a bunch of stuff to the bars depending on whether "this" or "that" is selected.

```
function render(selectedValue) {

if(selectedValue == "this") {

return data.this;

} else {

return data.that;

}

}
```

My render function is much more complicated and I have multiple branches of the conditional statement that all essentially repeat themselves. Is there any way for me to access a method of my data (i.e. data.this) when given the string "this" so that I don't have such a monstrous if-statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data["this"], or pass it a variable:

```
var b = "this";
return data[b];
```

Your code would look something like this:

```
function render(selectedValue) {
    return data[selectedValue];
}
```